# airflow read topic kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow, kafka-consumer-api

I want to see a message from a kafka topic in the airflow log

the dag does not give errors, but I don't get a print with messages in the log.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow_provider_kafka.operators.consume_from_topic import ConsumeFromTopicOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
def func(message, prefix=None):
    for message in get_messages:
        new_val=str(message.value)
        print(new_val)

with DAG(dag_id="test_kafka",
         start_date=datetime(2021,1,1),
         schedule_interval='@weekly'
         ) as dag:
         get_messages=ConsumeFromTopicOperator(
          task_id="get_messages",
          topics=["topictest"],
          apply_function='test_kafka.func',
          consumer_config = {
            'group.id':'test-consumer-group',
            'bootstrap.servers': 'server:9092',
            "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",})

get_messages
```

Comment: I assume the topic isn't empty? server:9092 is resolvable? And you've tried adding more print statements such as before the operator definition and before the consumer loop to debug, and those do get printed? Also, `get_messages` is not defined in your `func`

Comment: Try running the included example first https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/main/example_dags/hello_kafka.py

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, the topic is not empty, I just want to print a message

Comment: I'm trying this library, but not successfully

Comment: Not the library itself. Try running the example DAG there with a brand new topic? Otherwise, seems to me that you need to indent `get_messages` from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(message, prefix=None):
    for message in get_messages:
        new_val=str(message.value)
        print(new_val)
```

Your callable won't work. Get_messages will be by default "None" as it is never defined. The callable is applied to each message individually so all you need is "print".

```
def consumer_function(message, prefix=None):
    print (message.value())
    return
```

Comment: Did not help message not received :(

Comment: Have you attempted to run : 
https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/main/example_dags/hello_kafka.py  ?

I'm the author of this package and at this point i have to believe that there are no messages or you've got multiple processes using the same group id , so your being pulled to the end of the offset w/o knowing it.

Comment: help with correct code

Comment: I'm doing an "auto.offset.reset": "earliest", why do I have the end of the offset? there are messages in the topic, that's for sure, I added the words there, if I use this function with python, I get this function from my topic

Comment: Have you run the example DAG ? Verify that works please.

Comment: Yes, I ran a dag and it works, but this one doesn’t, if you have a slack airflow, please look, I painted the problem there and posted the log channel random